# Use jQuery SimpleModal to open an HTML file as a modal window

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

How can I use `jQuery` SimpleModal to open an html file as a modal window? Assume, On a `TTM_1.html` file I have a `anchor` and when I click on it show `TTMD.html` in a modal window.

Thanks.

Comment: Eric is the developer of simplemodal buddy. If he suggested a solution I think it would be the best to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of different ways:

Load the data:

```
$(YOUR_ANCHOR).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // load the html file using ajax
    $.get("TTMD.html", function(resp){
        var data = $('<div></div>').append(resp);
        data.modal();
    });
});
```

Use an iframe:

```
$(YOUR_ANCHOR).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // change height, width and modal options as required
    $.modal('<iframe src=""TTMD.html" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
        closeHTML:"",
        containerCss:{
            backgroundColor:"#fff",
            borderColor:"#fff",
            height:450,
            padding:0,
            width:830
        },
        overlayClose:true
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to use the first method but I can't figure out how to use it. Can you show me a working example of it to make it a little clearer?